# What is the minimum amount for a re-raise?

Tags: rules, raise

Consider the following situation (playing pokerTH on Ubuntu) :
In the TURN round only two players are left. Me and Player One.

1. I bet $20
2. Player One bets $120
3. I get the next chance to either Call ($100) or Raise. Computer tells me the min raise should be $200.

According to my understanding Raise amount should be (Call + Big Blind) but in this round there is no big blind. So what is happening here?

Comment: Anyway who would want to make a smaller raise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is telling you to raise it would be 200. That is 100 as a call and 100 as a raise.

When you think of the big blind think of it as a bet, that is all it is, a bet like any other, as far as how much you can raise. Keep it that simple.